# Avoid warnings when using jest to test that data corresponds to TypeScript types

Tags: typescript, testing

In the example below I want to verify that the data actually gives med a `project` with a property `id`.

```
test('getActiveProject => Project', async () => {
    let previouslyOpenProject = await client.getActiveProject()
    if (!previouslyOpenProject) {
        previouslyOpenProject = await client.createProject();
    }
    let project = await client.getActiveProject();
    expect(project.id).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);
});
```

I get the following ts error message

> [ts] Object is possibly 'null' (referring to project and the use of
>   project.id)

What is a good course of action from here:

- Should I write my tests in js instead of ts?
- Should I find a testing framework with a TypeScript pre-processor that will allow me to use TypeScript types in test expectations? (I don't think this exists)
- Should these kinds of checks be made by some kind of json validation scheme instead of jest tests?

Comment: Use `project!.id`?

Comment: Or you can do something like this `let project = await client.getActiveProject() as Project;` where `Project | null` is type of result from `getActiveProject`

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak: That sounds pretty good! I'll go with that

Comment: Glad to help :). I will put this code as response to be more visible for others, ok?

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak: That sounds good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result type fo `getActiveProject` is `Project | null`. If you are sure that `let project` is not null you can map it by `let project = await client.getActiveProject() as Project;`.

Also you can do something like this

```js
let project = await client.getActiveProject(); // without type mapping
if (project !== null) {
  // here project will be Project type, not a Project | null
}
```